# A* Pathfinding issue

Tags: java

I looked over numerous articles on A* pathfinding and after looking at pseudo-code, I have tried to make my own.

I have a Node class:

```
private int x, y;

//The cost of movement (g) and the heuristic (h)
private int g;

private Node parent;

public Node(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public Node(int x, int y, Node parent) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.g = parent.getG() + 1;
}

public boolean equals(Node node) {
    return (this.x == node.getX() && this.y == node.getY() && this.parent.equals(node.getParent()));
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public Node getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Node parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public int getF(Node goal) {
    return g + getH(goal);
}

public int getG() {
    return g;
}

public void setG(int g) {
    this.g = g;
}

public int getH(Node goal) {
    int dx = Math.abs(this.x - goal.getX());
    int dy = Math.abs(this.y - goal.getY());
    return (dx + dy);
}
```

}

Pathfinding:

```
public Path getPath(Node start, Node goal) {
    ArrayList<Node> openset = new ArrayList<Node>();
    ArrayList<Node> closedset = new ArrayList<Node>();

    //Add current position to open set
    openset.add(start);

    while(!openset.isEmpty()) {
        //Current node = node with lowest F score
        Node current = getNodeWithLowestScore(openset, goal);
        closedset.add(current);
        openset.remove(current);

        if(closedset.contains(goal)) {
            System.out.println("PATH FOUND.");
            break;
        }

        ArrayList<Node> adjacentNodes = getAdjacentNodes(current, closedset);

        for(Node n : adjacentNodes) {
            if(closedset.contains(n)) {
                continue;
            }

            if(!openset.contains(n)) {
                n.setParent(current);
                openset.add(n);
            }else{
                if(n.getF(goal) > (current.getG() + n.getH(goal))) {
                    n.setParent(current);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public Node getNodeWithLowestScore(ArrayList<Node> openset, Node goal) {
    Node lowest = openset.get(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < openset.size(); i++) {

        Node n = openset.get(i);
        int nscore = n.getF(goal);

        if(nscore < lowest.getF(goal)) {
            lowest = n;
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}

public ArrayList<Node> getAdjacentNodes(Node node, ArrayList<Node> closedset) {
    ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

    nodes.add(new Node(node.getX() + 1, node.getY(), node));
    nodes.add(new Node(node.getX() - 1, node.getY(), node));
    nodes.add(new Node(node.getX(), node.getY() + 1, node));
    nodes.add(new Node(node.getX(), node.getY() - 1, node));

    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        if(nodes.get(i) == null || closedset.contains(nodes.get(i))) {
            nodes.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

}

It's not working, and if I print out the size of the open or closed set, the numbers soar so high. I tested this with a 30x30 2D grid, starting from 10, 10 (start) to 30, 30 (goal).

The changes I made so far:

getAdjacentNodes method ->

```
    ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

    nodes.add(new Node(node.getX() + 1, node.getY(), node));
    nodes.add(new Node(node.getX() - 1, node.getY(), node));
    nodes.add(new Node(node.getX(), node.getY() + 1, node));
    nodes.add(new Node(node.getX(), node.getY() - 1, node));

    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        int x = nodes.get(i).getX();
        int y = nodes.get(i).getY();
        if(!((x > 0 && x < 30) && (y > 0 && y < 30))) {
            nodes.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

the getPath method -> (inside the while(openset is not empty) method)

```
        Node current = getNodeWithLowestScore(openset, goal);
        openset.remove(current);

        if(current.equals(goal)) {
            System.out.println("PATH FOUND.");
            break;
        }else{
            closedset.add(current);
            ArrayList<Node> adjacentNodes = getAdjacentNodes(current, closedset);

            for(Node n : adjacentNodes) {
                if(closedset.contains(n) && (n.getG() > current.getG())) {
                    n.setG(current.getG());
                    n.setParent(current);
                }else if(openset.contains(n) && (n.getG() > current.getG())) {
                    n.setG(current.getG());
                    n.setParent(current);
                }else{
                    openset.add(n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your major problem is a small detail in

```
public boolean equals(Node node) {
    return (this.x == node.getX() && this.y == node.getY() 
         && this.parent.equals(node.getParent()));
}
```

in conjunction with

```
if(!openset.contains(n)) {
    n.setParent(current);
    openset.add(n);
}
```

It's hard to spot and it took me a while to figure it out.

[`ArrayList<>().contains(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) internally uses (with the help of [indexOf](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.contains%28java.lang.Object%29)) the method [`Object().equals(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), which takes an `Object` as a parameter.

Your `Node().equals(Node n)` method uses a `Node` parameter, thus not overwriting the `Object().equals(Object o)` method you want to overwrite.

To solve this you should change your method to:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof Node)) return false;
    return (this.x == node.getX() && this.y == node.getY() 
         && this.parent.equals(node.getParent()));
}
```

I don't know if there are more problems with your code since I have not a real clue about how you call it and how your Path class looks like and so on. I tried it from (0, 0) to (3, 2) and at least it terminated and the sizes seemed to be smaller after the fix.

Some NullPointerExceptions occured when I was calling `Node().getParent()` though, maybe you should have a look at that. For example in your `equals(Object o)` `this.parent` might be null, you should check it beforehand.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't the problem. :P

The problem that messed me up was that I was looking at multiple pseudo-code examples of the algorithm, and I realized that I didn't do the checks for the G cost and so forth.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!